# PDO lastInsertId does not work on transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO for the first time with MySQL, just playing with it at the moment.

So far when I try to do an insert wrapped in transactions...

```
$this->dbh->beginTransaction();
// $sql query ran
$this->dbh->commit();

echo $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
```

lastInsertId() is returning 0...when I run the same query outside of a transaction, I get the proper id number returned.  Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Call it before committing the transaction.

Comment: You've stumbled on a nasty habit of PDO, yes, you'll have to call `lastInsertId` _before_ `commit`, which is a pain, but easy enough to remember.

Comment: @Wrikken: I don't think it's nasty, and probably even intentional behavior, since transactions are often used to execute multiple `INSERT` statements. So, in order to get the `lastInsertId` of, say, the first `INSERT` statement in a transaction of 3 `INSERT` statements, you'd always have to call `lastInsertId` before doing a `commit`, because you'd have to call it before the other 2 `INSERT` statements.

Comment: @Wrikken: but, to be fair, that doesn't explain why it wouldn't remember the `lastInsertId` after the commit. Hmmm, maybe anybody else has a reasonable explanation?

Comment: @fireeyedboy: multiple `INSERT`'s, either inside or outside a transaction, have always had the same effect: the first id generated by the last statement is used. However, the MySQL command line is my test for anything, and there the last insert id _does not get lost_ when committing a transaction.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to ask for the `lastInsertId()` before you commit a `transaction`

Try

```
$this->dbh->beginTransaction();
// $sql query ran
echo $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
$this->dbh->commit();
```

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php#85129) as well.

Comment: This just saved me from jumping out a window. THANKS!

Comment: I too was about to jump out a window. Thank you