# PDO's lastInsertId() Returns the Correct ID on One Line But Not Another Where I Need It for a $_SESSION['xxxxxx'] =?

Tags: php, pdo

Im working on a login script but am having trouble with lastInsertId();

Here's the code;

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    db = new PDO("mysql:host=hostname;dbname=database name", user, password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    try { 
        $db->beginTransaction();
        $db->query("INSERT INTO `subscribers`(`subscribers`.`first_name`, `subscribers`.`last_name`) VALUES ('Jane', 'Doe')");
        $db->query("UPDATE `subscribers` SET `first_name`='John' WHERE `ID` =".$db->lastInsertId());
        $db->commit();
        $LastID = $db->lastInsertId();
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $LastID; 

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $db->rollBack();
        die($e->getMessage());
        }
?>
```

My problem is that the UPDATE query performs properly (based off of WHERE `ID` =".$db->lastInsertId());) but when I try to use the function for setting the $_SESSION as seen in the code all I get back is 0.

If anyone wouldn't mind showing me what's askew I'd be most appreciative and I thank you in advance.

Comment: @Madbreaks wouldn't that be the same as the inserted ID?

Comment: Also, I've tried $LastID = $db->lastInsertId();
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $LastID; above and below commit()

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$db->query("INSERT INTO `subscribers`(`subscribers`.`first_name`, `subscribers`.`last_name`) VALUES ('Jane', 'Doe')");
// Grab, save
$LastID = $db->lastInsertId();
// Query by last ID
$db->query("UPDATE `subscribers` SET `first_name`='John' WHERE `ID` =".$LastID);
$db->commit();
// Write last ID to session
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $LastID;
```

Comment: Hi @Madbreaks I tried this but I don't think $LastID = $db->lastInsertId(); is working because it's before commit() so I moved it below commit and commented out the UPDATE line and reran it but it still wont set the SESSION properly

Comment: No, you're calling `$db->lastInsertId()` in YOUR example code before the `$db->commit()` (in your `UPDATE` query) and you said that it works.  So my calling it in the same place should also work.

Comment: This is Bizarre. Unfortunately Im going to have to leave the office in about 5 mins but I very much appreciate everyones help

Comment: Whats bizarre is I put $LastID = $db->lastInsertId(); before commit() and the UPDATE query works WHERE `ID` =".$LastID BUT just below commit I tried $_SESSION['user_id'] = $LastID; but No Dice so I moved $_SESSION['user_id'] = $LastID; above commit and still no proper ID returned. (Yes, my id column is set to Auto Inc)

Comment: You're getting confused, or your `$_SESSION` hasn't been initialized properly, etc.  There's nothing magic happening here.  Try reading/echoing the session var immediately after you set it (whether it's before or after `$db->commit()` makes no difference whatsoever).

Comment: Hi @Madbreaks, I have echoed it. It returns "0"

Comment: Also, If I manually set SESSIOn to something such as = 1 (My personal ID in the DB) everything works properly from there outward. (ie: Welcome $var['first_name']; displays my first name throughout the site as it should. However, with the code above and after following everyone's suggestions $_SESSION['user_id'] = $LastID; returns a 0. YET the UPDATE query works with $LastID

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `update` destroys the `lastInsertId` of your `insert`.
Try storing the id in a variable for use later:

```
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `subscribers`(`subscribers`.`first_name`, `subscribers`.`last_name`) VALUES ('Jane', 'Doe')");
    $last_id=$db->lastInsertId();
    $db->query("UPDATE `subscribers` SET `first_name`='John' WHERE `ID` =".$last_id);
    $db->commit();
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $last_id
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this tip. I haqd wished I knew how to write that. I was thinking of storing this in a variable, I just didn't know how or where. Huge Thanks!! Gimme a few minutes while I try this.

BTW, You'll notice I was trying to piece this together underneath commit();

Comment: You had the right idea. As Danijel mentioned, when using transactions, `lastInsertId` has to be called before the `commit`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906336/pdo-lastinsertid-does-not-work-on-transactions#6906383